# scatter_style for drawing a scatter chart using Axlsx gem does not work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scatter-plot, axlsx

---

I'm using Axlsx gem on rails 4 to draw a scatter plot with marker style. Here's the code that I have:

```
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Scatter Chart") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["First",  1,  5,  7,  9]
  sheet.add_row ["",       1, 25, 49, 81]
  sheet.add_row ["Second", 5,  2, 14,  9]
  sheet.add_row ["",       5, 10, 15, 20]
  sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::ScatterChart, :title => "example 7: Scatter Chart") do |chart|
    chart.scatterStyle = :marker
    chart.start_at 0, 4
    chart.end_at 10, 19
    chart.add_series :xData => sheet["B1:E1"], :yData => sheet["B2:E2"], :title => sheet["A1"]
    chart.add_series :xData => sheet["B3:E3"], :yData => sheet["B4:E4"], :title => sheet["A3"]
    puts chart.scatter_style
  end
end
```

Even though I change the scatterStyle to :marker, the chart is still in lineMarker style. I tried all other possible styles but it does not seem to be working for me. When I print chart.scatterStyle, it gives me "marker" which means the style has been changed, but what I see is again in lineMarker style. Is there something else I should do?

Comment: I have this exact same issue right now (with a different option desired for scatter_style, but still), hoping someone has an answer here.